# Switching scene mode between Global and Local in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, global-scene, local-scene

From its [online help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/map-authoring/go-3d-with-arcgis-pro.htm):

> ArcGIS Pro includes two viewing modes for scenes:
>
> - Global mode—This is used for large extent, real-world content where the curvature of the earth is an important element.
> - Local mode—This is used for smaller extent content in a projected coordinate system, or cases where the curvature of the earth isn't
>     needed.

I suspect that it is not possible to switch a scene from Global to Local mode (or *vice versa*).

If it is, can someone tell me how to do it, or if not can someone confirm that by perhaps pointing at some documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the View tab on the Ribbon in ArcGIS Pro you will see on the left hand side the buttons global and local. This will convert your scene from the global scene you started with to a local scene where you can further change the coordinate system of the local scene.

[image]